# Flixel - FlxWeapon not showing any bullet

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, flixel

I tried to make some bullets(actually swords/daggers) using FTP FlxWeapon, but some unexpected results was given.
This is how I set up the FlxWeapon:

```
    sword = new BasicSword("Sword", player, "x", "y");
            sword.makeImageBullet(15, BasicSword.SWORD_GIF,5);
            sword.setBulletDirection(FlxWeapon.BULLET_RIGHT, 400);  
            sword.setPreFireCallback(bulletDirectionCallback);
    //load FlxControl

        if(FlxG.getPlugin(FlxControl) == null){
            FlxG.addPlugin(new FlxControl);
        }
        FlxControl.player1.setFireButton("X", FlxControlHandler.KEYMODE_PRESSED, 100, sword.fire);

        }
/*A callback function, to set a proper direction before we fire the sword*/
        public function bulletDirectionCallback():void{

            if(player.facing == FlxObject.RIGHT){
                sword.setBulletDirection(0, 400); //make the bullet move to the right side with velocity of 400.
            }
            else{ //if player is facing the left direction.
                sword.setBulletDirection(180, 400); //make the bullet move to the left side with the velocity of 400.

            }

        }
```

Important notes:
BasicSword.as extends Sword.as and Sword.as extends FlxWeapon.
There's nothing important in BasicSword & Sword , actually Sword has only the constructer and BasicSword has only SWORD_GIF.
-What I think is working:

1-The callback function.
2-some methods and variables, like: setFireRate() and bulletsFired.
3-The fire button(FlxControl.player1.setFireButton).

-What is not working:
1-The sword is not showing up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my bug by putting this code`FlxG.worldBounds.make(0,0,level.width, level.height);` after the level is loaded itself because earlier(when I had the bug) I put this code after creating the level object BUT before loading it. so the value of `level.width` and `level.height` was 0 and 0.